# No User Authentication, so how can i secure my http request?

Tags: android, rest, security, httprequest, token

I am developing an android application that uses `HTTPurlConnection` to send a `JSON` request to my `REST Service`.

At the minute, I am just sending a string which has been hardcoded to my REST service and then my `REST service` is expecting the same string.

However, now that I am going to be releasing my app into production in my business I am aware of the dangers and I know that this is a very unsafe means of secure requests.

If I have no user sign in, what is the best form or piece of code I can use to secure/encrypt the token that I am sending my `HTTP request`?

Would appreciate the help! Thanks

Comment: @TheCodeStar any ideas?

Comment: What you want is not possible, you can't authenticate the app itself. Anything the app has would also be available for the user, who could use any secret in a different app.

Comment: @GaborLengyel awh right okay, not even something like a generated key or something ?